# Python PDM + pre-commit using pylint: imports cannot be found

Tags: python, pylint, pre-commit.com, python-pdm

## Background

I am wrangling some legacy code into shape.

I use [PDM](https://pdm.fming.dev/) to manage dependencies, which places all dependent packages in a `__pypackages__` folder directly under the repo root level.  PDM also uses the relatively new `pyproject.toml` package config file.

I am trying to adopt [`pre-commit`](https://pre-commit.com/) Git hooks so that I can have automated checks for formatting and style before trying to commit, merge, and/or create PRs.

I am asking `pre-commit` to use only a few Python tools for now:  [`pylint`](https://pylint.org/) and `black`.

## Issue

Most of that toolset works great together.  However, `pylint` cannot find any of the modules that are stored in the `__pypackages__` folder.  Most of what I have read suggests that I alter my `$PYTHONPATH` to find the modules.

This solution seems very outdated.  But also, I am not sure how I can do this in a robust way across the team.  I can alter the Git hooks, but the `$PYTHONPATH` may be different for each engineer, so this will only work for my machine.

I would **like** to be able to add something in the `pyproject.toml` file to have `pylint` find it.  I am not sure what to write, though, so that it generically works across the whole team.  Something like

```
[tools.pylint]
pypackages = "./__pypackages__"
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

## Details

I am not sure more details are needed, but here it is:

My actions:

```
> pre-commit run --all-files # The --all-files flag is just to allow me to test without a commit
Trim Trailing Whitespace.................................................Passed
Fix End of Files.........................................................Passed
Check Yaml...........................................(no files to check)Skipped
Check for added large files..............................................Passed
black....................................................................Passed
pylint...................................................................Failed
- hook id: pylint
- exit code: 30

************* Module testfile
testfile.py:18:0: E0401: Unable to import 'boto3' (import-error)
```

`boto3` is in the `__pypackages__` mentioned above. None of the modules can be imported, but I limited the output for clarity.

I can `pdm run ...` everything correctly and VS Code sees the modules fine. But `pylint` is not finding it because it cannot find this `__pypackages__` folder.

Comment: I don't know a lot about PDM but did you try installing pylint with pdm and then using a system hook for pylint ? Your pre-commit conf is not shown and it's important here as pylint need to be in the same env as your dependencies.

Comment: It's possible to write Python code such that pylint *can't* handle it, because pylint doesn't actually *run* it so any secret changes you've made to `sys.path` in a module don't happen. Pylint does however try to handle normal import cases by simulating what normal Python will do with normal `import` directives in normal situations. It's when you step too far outside these norms that this stuff fails. That might not be the problem, but it's worth considering.

Comment: That makes sense, regarding `sys.path`.  But I guess what is frustrating is that the `__pypackages__` folder *is* inside the root repo and *is* part of accepted Python package structures.  So pylint should know to treat the root path `__pypackages__` as a location to check for imports, the same way it checks any folder with a `__init__.py` file in it.  I guess I just have to wait for pylint to catch up to PEP 582.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get around this by updating the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable used by the extension, by creating a file named `.env` in your workspace (project folder) and adding the following entry:

```
PYTHONPATH=D:/commonScripts
```

Note: Relative paths are also supported.
Further info on `.env` files can be found here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file

Comment: Great, thanks!  It's great to hear from the author himself!  (BTW, I have become a PDM evangelist at my company.  I love it!)